# How do I separate a aggregate list from One Cell Into Separate Cells In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I separate a aggregate list from One Cell Into Separate Cells In Excel

From an aggregate list

A1

a;b;c;d;e;f;g

To separate Cells In Excel

a  b   c   d   e   f   g

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/483419/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-in-ms-excel

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",99)),COLUMNS($A:A)*99-98,99))
```

and copy across.

[image]